# numpy: insert array in place of an element

Tags: python, numpy, broadcast, valueerror

Input:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0]
])
```

Desired output:

```
b = np.array([
    [[0, 0],[1, 1], [0, 0]],
    [[1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
])
```

What I've tried:

```
b = np.where(a == 0, np.array([0, 0]), np.array([1, 1]))
```

The above code gives me a `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (<a's dimentions>) (2,) (2,)`

**Edit**: Bad example on my end. I thought making it simple would make it more readable. But I don't necessarily want `ones` in place of 1 and `zeros` in place of 0, and the input isn't limited to 0s and 1s. Instead, I want the input to be something like:

```
a = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 2, 0]
])
```

and the output to be:

```
b = np.array([
    [[5, 6],[8, 2], [5, 6]],
    [[8, 2], [7, 4], [5, 6]]
])
```

Comment: Edited my answer for the "general" case. Also, you are missing parenthesis in b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand dimensions and then repeat along the new dimension(or repeat then reshape):

```
np.repeat(np.expand_dims(a, axis=2), 2, axis=2)
```

Output:

```
[[[0 0]
  [1 1]
  [0 0]]

 [[1 1]
  [0 0]
  [0 0]]]
```

And if you want to have different output, now you can apply your condition to new array easier.

**UPDATE**: per edit on the post for a general case: Assuming you have a mapping dictionary (depending on your mapping, solution could be different)

```
map_dict = {0: [5, 6],
     1: [8, 2],
     2: [7, 4]}

indexer = np.array([map_dict.get(i, [-1,-1]) for i in range(np.amax(a)+1)])[a]
```

or in a more specific case if your mapping includes all integers between 0 and max(a), like your example, use this:

```
indexer = np.array([map_dict[i] for i in np.unique(a)])[a]
```

output:

```
[[[5 6]
  [8 2]
  [5 6]]

 [[8 2]
  [7 4]
  [5 6]]]
```

Comment: Could you check the Edit in OP please?

Comment: @stackexchange_account1111 I assume you have some sort of mapping dictionary. (otherwise please provide us with your mapping function to assist better). Please find the update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mask and [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
              [1, 2, 0]])

d = {0: [5, 6],
     1: [8, 2],
     2: [7, 4]}

# Initialize b              
b = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1], 2))

for k,v in d.items():

    m = a==k
    b += m[...,None] * np.tile(v, (a.shape[0], a.shape[1], 1))

b
array([[[5., 6.],
        [8., 2.],
        [5., 6.]],

       [[8., 2.],
        [7., 4.],
        [5., 6.]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the elements of `a` are valid row index values for the array `c`:

```
In [964]: c = np.array([[5,6], [8,2], [7,4]])                                                          
In [965]: a = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,2,0]])                                                              
In [966]: c[a,:]                                                                                       
Out[966]: 
array([[[5, 6],
        [8, 2],
        [5, 6]],

       [[8, 2],
        [7, 4],
        [5, 6]]])
```

This is the simplest interpretation of your specification.  If `c` isn't a 2d array like this, or `a` doesn't simply map on to rows, you'll have to do more work to transform them (and quite possibly loose most of the `numpy` array advantages).

I should stress that this is not an 'insert' or 'in-place' mapping.  `a` remains unchanged.  It is a (2,3) array, `Out[966]` is a (2,3,2) array.

Comment: Just a note that this works if the mapping `c` spans all the integers 0-N. A missing integer in between in `a`  will mess up with indices. For example if `c = np.array([[5,6], [8,2], [7,4]])` and `a = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,3,0]])` array indexing will fail.